# Oracle Object-Relational add method

Tags: oracle, plsql, object-relational-model

I'm learning oracle object-relational model. I already know how to declare, call methods.
but how can I add a new method to an existing object?

is there something like "alter table add function returns xxxxx" ??

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you're looking for the `alter type` statement: http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10759/statements_4002.htm